# checkbox (check and uncheck) changes the dropdownlist dynamically using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am new to javascript, jQuery and AJAX (Frontend) technologies. I have been working on backend. I need to create a dynamic page where, the page has 4 checkbox options and one dropdown list. Once I select the checkbox the dropdownlist should show dynamically depending on the checkbox selected. If I select 2 checkboxes, I need to show combined of both the list in the dropdownlist. Can anyone please guide me how to proceed or any sample code or reference I can look in it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which one of GET or POST type you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SOF. Ideally your question should have a specific direction so that we can help you. I've posted a sample code below based on the general idea I got from your question.

If you have a specific doubt, ask a question

```js
$(".check").click(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $("#dd").append("<option value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "'>" + $(this).attr("value"));
  } else {
    $("#dd").find("option[value='" + $(this).attr("value") + "']").remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="x1">Checkbox1</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="x2">Checkbox2</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="x3">Checkbox3</input>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="x4">Checkbox4</input>

<select id="dd">
  <option value="Default1">Default1</option>
  <option value="Default2">Default2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am looking something similar to this. Will start working on it. Thanks a lot.